# PHP: MX Lookup via Proxy

Tags: php

Using both nslookup via exec and also dns_get_mx.  But can't find any documentation on either to do an MX lookup for a domain via a proxy.

Is this possible?  Are there any utilities with Centos I can install to facilitate this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the command "dig", use it something like this

dig @myproxyserver -t MX domainiwant.com

you should be able to exec and parse that

Comment: I'm able to parse results fine.  Thats not the question.  I want to do this via a proxy if possible.  Lets say I'm checking 10 million records a month, would my ISP be happy about that?